# Pagekit: UndefinedFunctionException on line 413

Tags: php, symfony, pagekit

Hello I'm using this new open source software and encounter this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_substr() in
>   /home/managetl/public_html/beta/app/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php
>   on line 413

Here is the code on line **413**:

```
       return iconv_substr($s, $start, $length, $encoding).'';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: forgot to enable "mbstring" via easy apache. So if any runs into the error for pagekit the enable mbstring using easy apache.